# How to get the path of app(without app.exe)?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, filepath

I want to get the path of my app like: "\\ProgramFiles\\myApp", I try to use the following code:

```
string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase;
```

But it returns a path which has "\\myapp.exe" at the end.

I also tried:

```
string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

But it throws an “NotSupportedException”.

Is there any way to get a path without .exe at the end?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
path = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( path );
```

Answer (score 19):

`Application.StartupPath` should do that for you.

Update: from you edit I see that you are running on Compact Framework. Then Application.StartupPath will not work. This is the construct that I usually use then:

```
private static string GetApplicationPath()
{
    return System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

More simple than the rest:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
...
var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location)
```

Comment: ummm...it's simple but "Location" is not found(at least in Windows Mobile app).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Path.GetDirectoryName(string) method passing your original path string as parameter for this. What problem are you trying to solve? Maybe you really need something like working directory?

Comment: Thank you and danbyStrom, your guide works well. I'm trying to play sound using the wav file in my app's directory, so I need its directory(without app.exe).

Answer (score 0):

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this will return the file's name "myApp" just like the method's name mentions. Thanks for the guide on this method anyway.

Comment: Shucks!  That's what I thought you wanted. :)

Answer (score 0):

What about using a FileInfo object to extract the directory name?

In Vb.Net:

```
fi = New FileInfo(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly.Location)
path = fi.DirectoryName
```

Comment: "Location" is not found in C# app, but everything in () can be replaced by the filepath I wrote and it works. Thanks.

Comment: Doesn't `GetExecutingAssembly` need `()`? e.g. `GetExecutingAssembly()`, or is that just **C#**?

Answer (score 0):

If its an exe as in your case use:

```
    // Summary:
    //     Gets the path for the executable file that started the 
    //     application, not including the executable name.    
    Application.StartupPath
```