# What is the Windows CE equivalent of Application.StartupPath?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

I'm adding code to a program created to be used on Windows CE. My current problem is that Application.StartupPath isn't recognized. What is the Equivalent line of code I need to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881251/how-to-get-the-path-of-appwithout-app-exe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can retrieve it by

```
Path.GetDirectoryName (Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly ().GetName ().CodeBase);
```