# Can we retrieve the path where the application is installed?

Tags: c#, deployment

I have a simple app, which I want to install using click once deployment. I want to retrieve the path where the user installed the app for ex. check the following image:-

[image]

I want to retrieve the path which is entered by the user. Is it possible to retrieve that path? If it's possible please suggest a suitable method. The app is made in C#

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881251/how-to-get-the-path-of-appwithout-app-exe

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get folder path for ClickOnce application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359026/how-to-get-folder-path-for-clickonce-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to get the path the application is running from.

Just use:

```
using System.Reflection;
...
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location
```

this will give you the path of the Application.

If you want just the folder, you can use

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Comment: Your wording can be confusing and understood as using the `using clause`.